# After doing append not able to find the element in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi Guys i have this below code in JQuery, where i basically create a new select on the fly and and then when i try to find it i cannot find it . Please advice

```
 var parent = optionElement.parent();
    var strHTML = "";
    var tempClass = optionElement.attr("class");

        strHTML = "<select name='" + optionElement.attr("name") + "' id='" + optionElement.attr("id") + "' class ='" + optionElement.attr("class") + "' >" + GetSearchOptionFilteredData(sOpt, true) + "</select>";
        optionElement.remove();

        parent.append(strHTML);

    **alert(parent.find(tempClass).length); <-- this gives 0**
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
alert(parent.find('.'+tempClass).length);
```

In jQuery a class selector must be prefixed with a dot `.` (e.g. `.classname`), whereas an ID selector must be prefixed with a hash/pound sign `#` (e.g. `#myId`), otherwise the selector won't work.

Answer (score 1):

When using class name in jQuery selector you need to prefix it with `.`

Try this:

```
alert(parent.find("." + tempClass).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.` to search for classes.

Or:

Wrap `strHTML` in `$(..)` before appending.

```
strHTML= $(strHTML);
```

After that you can still access this object with `strHTML`.